# How to read this json string in Extjs store reader?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have this json string look like:

```
[{
        "totalCount" : 134
    }, {
        "items" : [{
                "id" : 1669,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101669"
            }, {
                "id" : 1670,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101670"
            }, {
                "id" : 1671,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101671"
            }, {
                "id" : 1672,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101672"
            }, {
                "id" : 1673,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101673"
            }, {
                "id" : 1674,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101674"
            }, {
                "id" : 1675,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101675"
            }, {
                "id" : 1676,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "1800mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101676"
            }, {
                "id" : 1677,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101677"
            }, {
                "id" : 1678,
                "check" : false,
                "name" : "2118mm趟门衣柜",
                "part_number" : "DP101678"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and my store look like:

```
var item_store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

    model:'ItemModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    pageSize: 5,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type:'json',
            root: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        },
        url: 'item_access.jsp?fullpage=true&item_cat=167&group_id='+groupId

    }
});
```

but it cant read the root node for the store ,now my table look like that:
only with two blank row,
look like are node totalCount and items:

[image]

so how should I config the reader to read that string??

that is my grid:

```
    var itemPanel=Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

    id: 'item-panel',
    title: '产品',
    store: item_store,
    columns: [
        { header: 'id',  dataIndex: 'id' , flex: 1 },
        { header: 'part_number',  dataIndex: 'part_number' , flex: 2 },
        { header: 'name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 3 },
        { xtype: 'checkcolumn',header: '可见', dataIndex: 'check' , flex: 2 ,
        listeners:{
                 checkchange: function(col, idx, isChecked) {
                    var view = itemPanel.getView(),
                        record = view.getRecord(view.getNode(idx));
                        postData(record.get('id'),"ITEM",isChecked);

                }
            }
        }

    ],
     region: 'center',
     layout: 'card',

    // paging bar on the bottom
    bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: item_store,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
        items:[
            '-', {
            text: 'Show Preview',
            pressed: pluginExpanded,
            enableToggle: true,
            toggleHandler: function(btn, pressed) {
                var preview = Ext.getCmp('gv').getPlugin('preview');
                preview.toggleExpanded(pressed);
            }
        }]
    }),
});
```

my model:

```
Ext.define('ItemModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty : 'id',
    fields : [{
            name : "name",
            convert : undefined
        }, {
            name : "id",
            type : types.INT
        }, {
            name : "part_number"
        }, {
            name : "check",
            type : types.BOOLEAN
        }

    ]

});
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console. also please show how you configure that store to your grid.

Comment: Can we also see the model?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong, you may try to change the JSON structure as mentionned below. Which version of Ext do you use?

Comment: @wared ,yes so strange.. my version is Ext JS 4.2.1, the `root` config has no effect.. spend my whole day T_T

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I could help you through a JsFiddle or a file sharing site.

Comment: @wared thank you ! let me prepare for it..

Comment: @wared http://jsfiddle.net/wBMek/1/   please forget the  bad UI and useless code, and I　do some modify with the json data for put in JsFiddle, the main line  from 286 to 294.. you can see `alert` totalcount when the page load, but root function never called..

Comment: I'm currently working on your problem. I'll give you a feedback soon.

Comment: I have amended my answer. I did my best to explain the problem in english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the data structure if possible :

```
{ "totalCount": 134, "items": [] }
```

---

### Edit

I have setup a quick test using `ext-all-debug.js` from version 4.2.0.663, the same as in your JsFiddle. At first glance, the problem comes from the line 41343 :

```
root = Ext.isArray(data) ? data : me.getRoot(data);
```

At this point `getRoot` - which refers to the `root` property somehow - is not called because `data` is an array. This is not a bug. I rather think that you misuse the JSON reader which is designed to consider an array not as a configuration structure, but as a record list. Sorry for repeating this but you'd better replace the array with an object as mentionned above. If it's not possible you'll have to bring some changes to the framework in order to make it suit your needs.

Comment: I think it should probably still respect if you have a custom root. I'll log a bug for this and get it resolved.

Comment: yes, thank you for your explain, so I must update the json format like that...   http://jsfiddle.net/jy1989/wBMek/4/   working now..

Answer (score 2):

In the 4.x series you can pass functions for both the root/total:

```
totalProperty: function(data) {
    return data[0].totalCount
},
root: function(data) {
    return data[1].items
}
```

Comment: for your code, the `totalProperty` is work, but the `root` is not work, so strange... i print the console log for both two function, only `totalProperty` is called, `root` function not call..

Comment: Perhaps try updating to the latest version?